# Chamar serviço web via Ajax com função focusout

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net

```
 $("#<%=txtProduto.ClientID%>").on("focusout", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.post(AjaxService.Pessoa(<%=txtProduto.ClientID%>), function (data) {
                $("#<%=txtPrecoUnitario.ClientID%>").val(data);
            });

        });
```

Estou tentando chamar serviço serviço web via `Ajax`, e este tem parâmetros e deve me retornar um valor também.

O código acima foi o que tentei mas não funciona.

Comment: Você quer chamar um WebService? Você utiliza C#?

Comment: sim é em c#.. isso é um web service

Comment: vou assumir que está utilizando um WebMethod, tente remover o $.post e passar a função de callback como segundo parâmetro do método método AJAX: AjaxService.Pessoa(<%=txtProduto.ClientID%>, function(result) { ... });

Comment: Você usa asmx ou WCF?